# stormpath flask failed to init

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, stormpath

using `Flask-Stormpath` for token based authentication

when i'm rtying to register :
`http://localhost:5005/register`
getting the stormpath default registration .
when I fill in the details i'm getting an error `list index out of range`

when debugging inside the pip, i see the error is in `flask_stormpath/models` line 101
`current_app.stormpath_manager.application.accounts.create({
            'email': email,
...
})`

and the error is, specifically on :
`current_app.stormpath_manager.application`

This is how i'm initiating stormpath:

```
from flask.ext.stormpath import StormpathManager
app = Flask(__name__)
StormpathManager(app = app)
```

I'm thinking this is got something to do with lazy loading the application. but the error message is not very descriptive.

any clue how to debug this ?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: list index out of range

Comment: Please include the full traceback.

Comment: Please post your entire project code, as well as the error.

Comment: hi, found the error and created a pull request for you https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-flask/pull/67. it was failing to find the application which is not understood by `list index out of range`